# Implicitly differentiate $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have this practice problem before a test. Use implicit differentiation to find $dy/dx$ for the equation
$$x^3+y^3=3xy.$$
I have no idea how to do this, I didn't understand my lecturer. Can you guys show me the steps?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

Think of $y$ as a function of $x$. I will explicitly write this as $y(x)$. Then proceed to differentiate everything with respect to $x$ as normal, remembering the chain rule.

We need to differentiate $x^3 + y^3(x) = 3xy(x)$. Let's do each term one by one.

1. Differentiate $x^3$. You should quickly see this is $3x^2$.
2. To differentiate $(y(x))^3$, we need to remember the chain rule. This can be written in many different ways, but this is a composition of the functions $(\cdot)^3 \circ y \circ x$. The derivative is $3(y(x))^2 y'(x)$.
3. To differentiate $3xy(x)$, you must remember the product rule. The derivative is $3y*(x) + 3xy'(x)$.

So in total, differentiation yields
$$ 3x^2 + 3y^2(x) y'(x) = 3y(x) + 3xy'(x).$$
In this form, to find $y'$, you isolate it (if possible) in this equation. Here, this simplifies (after cancelling factors of $3$) to
$$ y'(x) = \frac{y(x) - x^2}{y^2(x) - x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Implicit differentiation is really quite simple. Think of $x$ as the independent variable, and think of $y$ as a function of $x$.

So, if you take the derivative of $x^9$ with respect to $x$, you get $9x^8$. But if you take the derivative of $y^9$ **with respect to** $x$, you get $9y^8\cdot y'$.

Why? It's exactly like taking the derivative of $[f(x)]^9$, so use the chain rule to get $9[f(x)]^8\cdot f'(x)$.

In an equation, some terms may contain $y$ and some may not, so you will typically find $y'$ scattered here and there on both sides after you differentiate implicitly. If your goal is to find the derivative, you will have to solve the resulting equation for $y'$, so your answer will usually involve both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: how do i derive 3xy?

Comment: @jb3navides, You may want to use the product rule.

Comment: The verb is "differentiate", not "derive". You ask how to differentiate $3xy$? Take the same approach as you would if you wanted to differentiate $3x(x^2-5x^3)$ -- use the product rule. The explicit product is $(3x)(y)$. You see how to proceed?

Comment: Note: in my previous comment, the result will be a sum of two terms, one involving $y$ and the other involving $y'$. That's what I meant in my answer when I said that $y'$ may end up being scattered about the equation after differentiating.